# Error on Adding Chrome Driver in selenium 2.4.2

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

On adding the below codes in Selenium 2.4.2

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

chrome window gets opened but 'some yellow color alert message displayed as' - You are using an unsupported command-line flag:--ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer.

Comment: Can you confirm if its 2.4.2 or 2.42?

Answer (score -1):

Do the following -

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("test-type")
```

Comment: how does this help for the OP? no real explanation.